# Crashs of MBP 13 mid-2010 (MC375LL/A)

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, performance, restart, reboot

I am using a a MBP 13 mid-2010 (MC375LL/A) with the following characteristics

```
MacBookPro 7,1
Intel Core 2 Duo 2.6GHz
RAM: 8Gb (2x4Gb in replacement of the 2x2Gb)
HDD: WD Blue 500Go 5400trs/min (in replacement of 320Go)
GPU: Nvidia 320M 256Mo
OSX: Maverick 10.9.1
```

Use: office software applications + Multimedia + scientific computing and development (one raeson for changing the RAM)

Since the middle of december 2013, the MBP crashes many times a day. It stops by many differents ways:

- black, white, blue, orange or green screen and freezes (I need to hold power button to shutdown);
- come back to logon screen;
- reboot (black text on gray brackground screen);
- screen with many multicolor lines;
- just freeze (I need to hold power button to shutdown);

These problems happen with battery (i need to change it (670 cycles)) but also with magsafe. When the MBP crashs, I am not doing special thing (sometimes just on website, sometimes on youtube watching video...) but it is very randomly.

Sometimes I can obtain a Kernel Panic but sometimes not.

You can find at the following link the last kernel panic I obtained [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4zhrmLHBz-WUml5ZTNyamlZbTA)

So I am looking for one solution to deal with this problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This sounds like a hardware error. I suspect your machine will need to take a trip to an Apple store (or other Apple repair place).

Comment: @OllyHodgson You confirm that I am thinking. The Apple Store is not close to me therefore I am looking if I can find a solution before I will go to the store.

Comment: In complement, I thought about a RAM problem (because I changed it with non-Apple RAM module). But I have tried the both module on both so-dimm slots and I obtained the same crashs....

Comment: Do you have Apple Care?

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11342 might be helpful?

Comment: @Robuust no that is why I am looking to one other solution. I will go to the Apple Store next week-end to obtained a non-free diagnose. Unfortunately, after reading many forums I think that the problem seems to come from the GPU and the repair cost more than 500€ (excluding battery change)...

Comment: @OllyHodgson Maybe, but I don't have the software disks with me and the D key don't open apple diagnostics or Apple Hardware Test.

Comment: @OllyHodgson I try to start Apple Hardware Test using "Option+D" (Internet Recovery) but my MBP is not supported by the Apple Hardware Test.... :-(